# How to dynamic ObjectMapper implementation for spring

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, objectmapper

The client can decide whether the PropertyNamingStrategy is SNAKE_CASE or CAMEL_CASE by adding it to the api parameter.

my idea is to do aop interceptor before entering the controller to customize ObjectMapper.

I have setPropertyNamingStrategy for ObjectMapper object but it only get first PropertyNamingStrategy set, values set after first time are not used.

```
@Aspect
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class NamingJsonAspect {
  private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @Pointcut("execution(public * com.nnv98..*Controller.*(..))")
  private void namingJson() {}

  @SneakyThrows
  @Before("namingJson()")
  public void doAround(JoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) {
    ServletRequestAttributes attributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
    assert attributes != null;
    HttpServletRequest request = attributes.getRequest();
    String namingJson = request.getParameter("namingJson");
    if(namingJson.equals("SNAKE_CASE")){
      objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
    }else {
      objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.LOWER_CAMEL_CASE);
    }
  }
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the JavaDoc for [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html).

What you are seeing is expected behavior, as explained in the JavaDoc: configuration can only be done before first read/write usage. After first usage, changing the configuration may have no effect or may result in errors. The JavaDoc also explains how you can work around the limitation.

Comment: yes, thank you for your support, I was really flawed in omitting the JavaDoc.